# Document Set and Document Set Content Columns

Tags: 2010, list-view, document-set

I have created a Document Set (with 10 columns) and added a Document type (with 11 columns) to the set. I have shared all but one Columns between the two. Now, I would like to hide the 11th column on the default view of Document Library - BUT - display it on the Document Set Content webpart.

It seems like I am not able to customize the columns displayed on the Document Set Contents webpart independent of the columns displayed on the default view of the parent Document Library of the Document Set. Is this even possible? Has anyone come across this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the document set is just a glorified folder, so you can use folder type specific views.

1. Modify the standard AllItems view as you want it at the top (excluding the column)
2. Down at the bottom of the Edit view page expand "Folders" and select "In the top-level folder" for "Show this view"
3. Create a new view based on AllItems
4. Make it default
5. Add the extra column
6. Again expand the "Folders" section, but this time set "Show this view" to "In folders of content type: YourDocSetType"

Comment: Thanks Per. Next question then. Would this affect the Document Set updates if I am using content type hub? In other words, after taking the above steps, would the Document Set still be updatable from cth?

Comment: This isn't affecting the content type in any way, it's purely creating views in the list

Answer (score 0):

This sadly is not possible out of the box.

The document set is a folder if you look at where it came from. The difference is that this folder received a custom homepage and some special features (like sharing metadata inside the document set etc.) and they called it document set.
The only thing you **could** do is to modify the homepage of the document set to include custom code which automatically selects a different view (of the underlying document library) once you are within the document set. Then you would also have to add code to the that view so that once you are *not* within the document set it switches back automatically to the default view.

Think of the document set as a folder with added metadata. You cannot choose a different view based on the folder you are in.